# Link to Visual Foxpro 9 from Access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010, visual-foxpro

I want to read some data from VFP 9 database using Access 2010.  I have tried downloading the ODBC driver but I am told to use the OLEDB driver instead on the MS site.  How do I link to a VFP table from Access 2010.

Comment: I was able to download the VFP 9 driver but then realized it only works with 32 bit Windows 7.  I am going to try to setup XP mode and run it from there.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the VFP Downloads page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vfoxpro/bb190232.aspx) (also cited in Jerry's answer) talks about how the VFP ODBC Driver is **"no longer supported"** (emphasis theirs), and offers more information [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/277772). That page says, in part...

> We strongly recommend that you use the OLE DB Provider for VFP to access VFP data. However, a stand-alone installation for the VFP ODBC driver is still available at the following Web site:
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/vfoxpro/bb190233.aspx

...but that link just redirects back to the VFP Downloads page where we started. Very frustrating.

Fortunately, the provider page at connectionstrings.com [here](http://connectionstrings.com/providers/microsoft-visual-foxpro-odbc-driver) provides a direct link to the VFP ODBC Driver installer [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/vfoxodbcdriver/Install/6.1/W9XNT4/EN-US/VFPODBC.msi). Note that it may be a 32-bit driver and, if so, it will only work with the 32-bit version of Access 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the VFP ODBC driver. Here is a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vfoxpro/bb190232.aspx

Comment: As Gord pointed out, that link doesn't actually get us to the ODBC driver installer.